# Spring Boot can not enable JPA Repositories for JAR files

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi I have two maven projects (not modules) in first maven project I have a data-jpa repository

UserRepository

```
package com.massoudafrashteh.code.spring.boot.dans.repository;
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
}
```

Then exported this project to a jar and attached to another boot application which I have a configuration like this inside

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
@EntityScan(basePackages ="com.massoudafrashteh.code.spring.boot.dans.domain")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.massoudafrashteh.code.spring.boot.dans.repository")
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public UserService userService() {
        return new UserServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

But Boot could not find my repository and said

> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.massoudafrashteh.code.spring.boot.dans.repository.UserRepository'
>   in your configuration

Used "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.5.3.RELEASE" in both projects. I think the problem is that I have a @Bean for UserServiceImpl and spring can not find the implementation of Data JPA at runtime!

**Update1:**
When I test both as maven modules they work! but they won't work as a jar file!

**Update2:**
there is no other configuration, I just used HSQLDB which Spring-Boot manage the DB.

**Update3:** As I got should use a boot project as a dependeny. Please take a look at both projects, spring-rest-test is the executable project, https://gitlab.com/massoud.afrashteh/spring-boot-template. Thanks

Comment: can you show your application.properties or yml file ?

Comment: There is no application.properties in both projects

Comment: have you tried making the repository work in the first maven project? Or if you declare a repository in the second maven project and try to use it, does it work?

Comment: OK then boot works well in both side but can not load another project stuff!

Comment: I have just tried autowiring repository in a multi module project between the modules. This is essentially same a using the Repository from another jar. I think there is some other problem with your component scanning. Can you please do one more check? Can you define a sample bean in the package "com.massoudafrashteh.code.spring.boot.dans.repository" with @Component annotation and see if you are able to autowire it in UserServiceImpl?

Comment: what if you try this : @ComponentScan("com.package.where.my.class.is")

Comment: @yaswanth data jpa will automatically find the repositories without any annotation if the interface extendes JpaRepository or CrudRepository. I also added component and does not work

Comment: @georgesvan not worked because I have some other packages in my second spring boot project started with "com". the absolute problem is EnableJpaRepository

Comment: @MassoudAfrashteh ohh yeah. my bad. I am not sure what the issue is in that case. But there seems to be a bug in your code. You have annotated UserServiceImpl with \@Service and enable ComponentScan on "com" package. You have again declared the bean via \@Bean annotation in Configuration class. So one of those configurations override the other depending on the order or loading. You can try removing the \@Bean from Config class. But I don't think even that will help.

Comment: If you had opted for springboot `actuators`, try to access `/beans` uri and check if there is any bean created by spring container?

Comment: Also, can you paste `UserService` class?

Comment: @harshavmb UserService is just an interface!

Comment: @yaswanth in a multi-medule case they work but can not work with JARs!

Comment: Show your DataSource and TransactionManager configurations.

Comment: @shazin used HSQLDB thele is no configuration for them, Spring-boot do them automatically

Comment: @MassoudAfrashteh multi module is no different from exporting it in a jar. Modules are built into jars separately and added as a dependency in the pom.

Comment: @yaswanth Yeah I know but in this case boot won't work with JARs please check a jar one you will get my error then

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to use a Spring Boot application as a dependency. If so, have you read [this section of the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar)?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks as I got I put the suggested configurations in my executable boot mave project but again nothing :| let's push all codes somewhere and share the link.

Comment: OK guys please take a look at both projects, spring-rest-test is the executable project, https://gitlab.com/massoud.afrashteh/spring-boot-template. Thanks

Comment: @AndyWilkinson but if you take look at my codes that you can find the link in question, in my JAR just there are some java files with spring annotation, I mean it's not spring boot application actually

Comment: The code you have shared doesn't compile

Comment: @AndyWilkinson have you exported a Jar from spring-boot-dans project and inject it to spring-rest-test?

Answer (score 0):

Your UserServiceImpl class is already defined with @Service annotation and it has some autowired dependant beans too.

Why don't you autowire your UserServiceImpl into the class where you needed instead of creating a new instance yourself and configuring as a bean with @Bean on method.

Comment: Because Spring can not inkect it, if you checked my last update and as spring documentation said we can not use a boot application as a dependeny when we have no module. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar

Comment: you cannot use boot application as a dependant but in your case, UserServiceImpl is not a boot application and it is a simple jar as you mentioned and this can be used by any boot application / any spring project if it is in the classpath. Also when you create new instance of UserServiceImpl its dependant classes are not injected through autowire.

Comment: OK so please clone my codes and check them you will get my error. thanks